# Flow doesn't complain with incompatible ReactClass usage and JSX

Tags: flowtype

I believe the following should be caught by flow:

```
type MyProps = {
  foo: boolean,
};
const makeComponent = (C: ReactClass<MyProps>) => <C />;
```

From reading [the source](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.50.0/lib/react.js#L89), I believe I am understanding `ReactClass` correctly.

What gives? This seems to also work with `React.createElement(C, {})`

On the other hand, the following breaks:

```
import MyComponent from '...'; // this component has props MyProps
const makeComponent = () => <MyComponent />;
// and likewise with React.createElement
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/2159#issuecomment-236099652) comment, `ReactClass` is buggy at best and should not be used. You can use the following instead:

```
type MyProps = {
  foo: boolean,
};
const makeComponent = (C: Class<React.Component<void, MyProps, void>>) => <C />;
```

Note that the parameters for `React.Component` are `defaultProps`, `Props`, and `State`. In the above example it is assumed that the component does not have either `defaultProps` or `State` defined, hence the `void` values.